# Nextjs redirect authorized users to dashboard

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

I am trying to figure out how is the best way to redirect users to the dashboard from homepage if they are already logged in. I am not using NextAuth just JWT.

From a server component I can do a quick check and see if there is a valid jwt and redirect them. That works but if they log out then go to the homepage again they will still be redirected to dashboard because I get the old value of the jwt.

```
export default async function AuthRedirectServer({ children }: Props) {
  async function checkAuth() {
    try {
      const token = cookies().get(config.jwtRefreshName)?.value

      const { uId } = await verifiyToken(token)

      if (!uId) return false

      return true
    } catch (err) {
      return false
    }
  }

  const isAuth = await checkAuth()

  if (isAuth) {
    redirect('/dashboard', RedirectType.replace)
  }

  return <>{children}</>
}
```

From a client component I can check if there is a user in the AuthProvider that I have. But then when the app first loads the homepage will flash real quick before I can fetch the users information.

```
export default function AuthRedirect({ children }: Props) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { user } = useAuth()

  if (user) {
    router.push('/dashboard', { replace: true })
    return null
  }

  return <>{children}</>
}
```

I also have tried making a dedicated api route to check the auth status from a server component but I can't get the jwt on initial load because the server hasn't made it to the client to get the cookies yet. And there is no point in calling it from a client component because I am already getting the user info on initial load anyway. I have also tried middleware but if i log out and then the first link I hit is the homepage I seem to get cached results there too.

So is there any way when a user logs out I can get the updated token status from a server component? Or is there a better way of going about this that I'm not thinking of? Any help would be appreciated.